# My humanoid aliens inhabit a rainforest planet and are super smart -- what do they look like?

Tags: xenobiology

I'm currently working on a sci-fi game and need some ideas for one of the alien species.
They live on a rain forest planet and are one of the most intelligent species in the game. They also need to be pretty humanoid due to technical limitations. They will be added in a later update but I still need to have an idea for what they look like. Sorry there isn't much information to go off of but I actually don't know what else to put here.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding! Unfortunately this is a brainstorming question. These don't go down well around here, and tend to be closed for being too broad.

Comment: Oh I didn't know that. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: *What would humans that evolved in a rain forest instead of a savanna look like?* Short. Long arms. Because they still (always will) climb trees because there's no where to run flat-out anyway. And hairy for some reason even though their body temp is only about 20f below ambient. "[gorilla] fur helps them to survive in a habitat where temperatures often drop below freezing." IDK that happened in rain forests. But if you're wet and it's windy you can get hypothermia even if it's 70f.

Comment: "super smart" means they started building houses, wear clothes, and so *started* not being so hairy. And they're all Caucasian because they never hung out in the sun. So, they're a bunch of gangly white neckbeards. Save money by filming on location in Kansas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Slug Men

[image]

Since they live in a humid environment, I am thinking something that needs to be constantly kept moist. Something like a slug-man or toad man. With an oily, scintillating surface that also works as a lung/gills.

[image]

Another thing that needs to be kept moist is nasal membranes. So you might as well have the creature's entire body work as a nose. They can taste and smell through every part of their body.

You can go one step further and have this taste/smell power be their primary form of communication. They join hands and emit complicated bouquets to talk to each other. It is hard to develop a vocal language when you have no rigid body parts.

The slug men can use their slime and powerful musclefoot to climb the tall trees in the rainforest in search of the tastiest leaves. Add in a hard shell, and your slug men become snail-men!

If the above image is too inhuman for you, consider something like this:

[image]

The antennae on the little green man's head look like the sensory tentacles on a slug or snail. And he has a slimy green skin. Maybe the little green man is evolved from Martian snails?

Comment: Are these slug men vertebrates? I’m not saying invertebrates can’t be intelligent, but their slug heritage does seem to be a strike against them.